# PeriodFormatter - How to prepend 0s if the hours or minutes happens to be a single digit number?

Tags: java, formatting, jodatime, period

When I use `PeriodFormatter` as below

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours()
                .appendLiteral(":").appendMinutes().appendLiteral(":")
                .appendSeconds().toFormatter();
```

I get the output as `4:39:9` Which means 4 hrs 39 mins and 9 seconds.

How to modify the formatter to produce `04:39:09`? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `.printZeroAlways()` and `.minimumPrintedDigits(2)`:

```
    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways()
        .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .appendHours()
        .appendLiteral(":")
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendLiteral(":")
        .appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at minimumPrintedDigits.  It should do what you want.

[http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html#minimumPrintedDigits(int)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html#minimumPrintedDigits%28int%29)